# Largest Fraction Smaller than a Given Fraction

Tags: prime-numbers, supremum-and-infimum, integers

Suppose that we have a fraction $\frac ab$ where $a$ and $b$ are mutually prime positive integers. What is the largest fraction $\frac cd$ where $c$ and $d$ are mutually prime positive integers such that $\frac cd < \frac ab$ and $c \le a$ ?

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you worked a lot of examples?  First couple I tried resulted in $\frac {a-1}{b-1}$, are there counterexamples to that pattern?  (note:  I restricted myself to the case $a<b$).

Comment: For $a/b = 7/5$ we have $c/d = 4/3$. Your example doesn't work because it does not necessarily result in mutually prime numbers.

Comment: I specified $a<b$.  But cheap counterexamples to my pattern are things like $\frac 1n$, for which the answer is clearly $\frac 1{n+1}$.

Comment: Writing out a list of examples might help people to spot a pattern, if one exists.  Is there any reason to imagine that a useful pattern exists?

Comment: Yes. The area of a triangle with vertex coordinates at $(0,0), (b,a), (d,c)$ will always have an area of $1/2$.

Comment: Oh, from Pick's Theorem?  I suppose that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't help answer my question. I want to prove that the area is $1/2$ without using Pick's Theorem.

Comment: @lulu The restriction a < b doesn't affect coprimality. The counterexample 7/5 ->6/3 can easily be change to 3/7 ->2/6.

Comment: @Acccumulation  Sure, but failure of co-primality doesn't, on its own, invalidate my guess (just reduce my expression).  $a>b$ would imply that $\frac {a-1}{b-1}>\frac ab$ which certainly does invalidate my guess.  As I pointed out, though, there are plenty of cheap counterexamples to what I wrote.

Comment: @lulu If 2a<b+1, then a/(b+1) > (a-1)/(b-1).

Comment: @Acccumulation  Yes.  As I have said, my first guess was incorrect.

Comment: I think (but am not certain) that the answer must be related to [Farey fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence) in a fundamental way.  Loosely speaking, keep writing out Farey sequences until your fraction appears and then it's left hand neighbor is the desired answer.  This is not exactly correct, as you need to go one more step if your fraction appears alongside $0$.  Not sure if there are other exceptions.

Comment: To clarify:  it is certainly true that your desired answer is a left neighbor of the starting fraction in some Farey sequence.  The question is, then:  is there a sensible way of identifying the right Farey sequence?

Comment: Is this even possible? You can always find a rational number between two rationals.

Comment: @Vasya  The condition $c≤a$ means that there are only finitely many relevant fractions to test.

Comment: @lulu: I see. Then why not take $\frac{a}{b+1}$?

Comment: @Vasya  Doesn't always work.  For $\frac ab=\frac 67$ we have $\frac 68<\frac 56<\frac 67$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this always works. The fraction you want is the positive integers $c,d$ such that $c \leq a$  and
$$  ad - bc = 1. $$
First, there is such a pair. I am taking $a > 1, b > 1.$ The penultimate convergent $x/y$ in the continued fraction for $a/b$ solves $x < a, y < b,$ and either $ay-bx = 1$ or $ay-bx = -1.$ In the first case we have it, take $c=x, d=y.$ ADDED: recall that continued fraction convergents are alternately above and below the final value.  In the other case, we have $a(-y) - b(-x) = 1,$ so $a(b-y) -b(a-x) = 1 \; ; \;$ in this case, we actually had $\frac{x}{y} > \frac{a}{b},$ clearly unsuitable as it stands. This was the case in comment below with  $\frac{3}{2} > \frac{7}{5} \; .$

Next, Lemma 2.6 on page 13 of Edward B. Burger, *Exploring the Number Jungle* says: Let $\frac{p}{q} < \frac{r}{s}$ be two rational number satisfying $ps -rq = -1.$ Suppose that $a/b$ is a rational number satisfying $\frac{p}{q} \leq \frac{a}{b} \leq \frac{r}{s}.$ Then there exist nonnegative integers $\lambda$ and $\mu$ such that
$$  a = \lambda p + \mu r \; , \; \; \mbox{and} \; \; \; b = \lambda q + \mu s \; \; . $$ 
Proof: take $$ \lambda = br - as \; , \; \; \mu = a q - b p .  $$
Note that, if we have the stronger $\frac{p}{q} < \frac{a}{b} < \frac{r}{s},$ we actually get
$ \lambda, \mu \geq 1.  $

Back to our original letters, with $  ad - bc = 1, $ if $e/f$ is a rational number strictly between them, then $e > a.$

experiments

```
Mon Apr 30 17:46:51 PDT 2018
     a     b     c     d       a d - b c  
     1     2     1     3           1
     2     1     1     1           1
     1     3     1     4           1
     3     1     2     1           1
     1     4     1     5           1
     2     3     1     2           1
     3     2     1     1           1
     4     1     3     1           1
     1     5     1     6           1
     5     1     4     1           1
     1     6     1     7           1
     2     5     1     3           1
     3     4     2     3           1
     4     3     1     1           1
     5     2     2     1           1
     6     1     5     1           1
     1     7     1     8           1
     3     5     1     2           1
     5     3     3     2           1
     7     1     6     1           1
     1     8     1     9           1
     2     7     1     4           1
     4     5     3     4           1
     5     4     1     1           1
     7     2     3     1           1
     8     1     7     1           1
     1     9     1    10           1
     3     7     2     5           1
     7     3     2     1           1
     9     1     8     1           1
     1    10     1    11           1
     2     9     1     5           1
     3     8     1     3           1
     4     7     1     2           1
     5     6     4     5           1
     6     5     1     1           1
     7     4     5     3           1
     8     3     5     2           1
     9     2     4     1           1
    10     1     9     1           1
     1    11     1    12           1
     5     7     2     3           1
     7     5     4     3           1
    11     1    10     1           1
     1    12     1    13           1
     2    11     1     6           1
     3    10     2     7           1
     4     9     3     7           1
     5     8     3     5           1
     6     7     5     6           1
     7     6     1     1           1
     8     5     3     2           1
     9     4     2     1           1
    10     3     3     1           1
    11     2     5     1           1
    12     1    11     1           1
     1    13     1    14           1
     3    11     1     4           1
     5     9     1     2           1
     9     5     7     4           1
    11     3     7     2           1
    13     1    12     1           1
     1    14     1    15           1
     2    13     1     7           1
     4    11     1     3           1
     7     8     6     7           1
     8     7     1     1           1
    11     4     8     3           1
    13     2     6     1           1
    14     1    13     1           1
     1    15     1    16           1
     3    13     2     9           1
     5    11     4     9           1
     7     9     3     4           1
     9     7     5     4           1
    11     5     2     1           1
    13     3     4     1           1
    15     1    14     1           1
     1    16     1    17           1
     2    15     1     8           1
     3    14     1     5           1
     4    13     3    10           1
     5    12     2     5           1
     6    11     1     2           1
     7    10     2     3           1
     8     9     7     8           1
     9     8     1     1           1
    10     7     7     5           1
    11     6     9     5           1
    12     5     7     3           1
    13     4     3     1           1
    14     3     9     2           1
    15     2     7     1           1
    16     1    15     1           1
     1    17     1    18           1
     5    13     3     8           1
     7    11     5     8           1
    11     7     3     2           1
    13     5     5     2           1
    17     1    16     1           1
     1    18     1    19           1
     2    17     1     9           1
     3    16     2    11           1
     4    15     1     4           1
     5    14     1     3           1
     6    13     5    11           1
     7    12     4     7           1
     8    11     5     7           1
     9    10     8     9           1
    10     9     1     1           1
    11     8     4     3           1
    12     7     5     3           1
    13     6     2     1           1
    14     5    11     4           1
    15     4    11     3           1
    16     3     5     1           1
    17     2     8     1           1
    18     1    17     1           1
     1    19     1    20           1
     3    17     1     6           1
     7    13     1     2           1
     9    11     4     5           1
    11     9     6     5           1
    13     7    11     6           1
    17     3    11     2           1
    19     1    18     1           1
```

Comment: How does this allow us to find the value of $c/d$ given $a/b$? The fact that $|ad-bc| = 1$ for the Farey neighbors gives us an equation in two variables $c$ and $d$, which is a step forward, but this still does not give us the singular solution where $c$ and $d$ are both integers and $c \le a$, even though this solution always exists.

Comment: @TheRiddler do you not know how to find the continued fraction of a number?

Comment: No. Please tell me how to do so in this context.

Comment: Something's not right. From what I've learned about continued fractions the penultimate convergent $x/y$ for $7/5$ is $3/2$ not $4/3$.

Comment: @TheRiddler $7 \cdot 2 - 5 \cdot 3 = -1,$ so we switch to $7 \cdot (5-2) - 5 \cdot (7 - 3) = 1$

Comment: Okay, this works.