# If $\frac{a}{c}<\frac{a'}{c'}<\frac{b}{d}$ and $bc-ad=1$, Then $a' = \lambda_1 a + \lambda_2 b$ and $c' = \lambda_1 c + \lambda_2 d$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, fractions

with $a,b,c,d>0$, and $c'>0$

I feel like this result follows from the denseness of the reals, but I am unsure how to prove it. Also, it is not obvious to me why $c'$ and $a'$ should have the same $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existence of a solution is a mere linear algebra problem: you want to solve
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 \\ \lambda_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a' \\ c' \end{pmatrix},
$$
which has a unique solution since the $ad - bc \ne 0$. Furthermore, using the given inequalities and the assumption that $bc - ad = 1$, you can prove that both $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are strictly positive.

Answer (score 2):

let us solve ( determinant is $-1$)
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
a' \\
c'
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Then
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
-d & b \\
c & -a
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
a' \\
c'
\end{array}
\right)
$$
so
$$  xa+yb = a' \; \; , \; \; \; xc +yd = c' \; \; , $$
also
$$ x = b c' - d a' > 0 \; \; ,  \; \;  y = ca' - a c' > 0  $$
because
$$\frac{a}{c}<\frac{a'}{c'}<\frac{b}{d} \; \; .$$

These are integers,
$$ x = b c' - d a' \geq 1 \; \; ,  \; \;  y = ca' - a c' \geq 1  $$
so
$$  a' \geq a+b \; \; ,  \; \; c' \geq c+d $$

This is the same information as at [Largest Fraction Smaller than a Given Fraction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2760731/largest-fraction-smaller-than-a-given-fraction)  a bit cleaned up this time.